# How to find the role on the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

The following code apparently works, it finds the user but doesn't find the role on the server

```
function checkAndAssignRole() {
    // Verificar si la tabla "roles" existe y si la columna "users" está presente en ella
    dbConnection.query("SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'saladeros_roles' AND table_name = 'roles' AND column_name = 'users' LIMIT 1", (err, columns) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        
        if (columns.length === 0) {
            // La columna "users" no está presente en la tabla "roles"
            console.log("La columna 'users' no está presente en la tabla 'roles'");
            return;
        }

        // La columna "users" está presente en la tabla "roles"
        console.log("La columna 'users' está presente en la tabla 'roles'");

        // Obtener el valor de la columna "users" de la primera fila
        dbConnection.query("SELECT users FROM roles LIMIT 1", (err, rows) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            
            if (rows.length === 0 || !rows[0].users) {
                // No se encontraron filas en la tabla "roles" o la columna "users" está vacía
                console.log("No se encontraron usuarios en la tabla 'roles'");
                return;
            }

            // Se encontró un usuario en la tabla "roles", obtener su ID
            const userId = rows[0].users;
            console.log("ID de usuario obtenida:", userId);

            // Obtener el servidor (guild) al que pertenece el usuario
            const guild = client.guilds.cache.first(); // Obtener el primer servidor al que el bot está unido
            if (!guild) {
                console.log("No se encontró el servidor");
                return;
            }

            // Esperar a que la caché de miembros esté completamente cargada
            guild.members.fetch().then(() => {
                // Obtener al usuario por su ID
                const user = guild.members.cache.get(userId);
                if (!user) {
                    console.log("No se encontró al usuario");
                    return;
                }

                console.log("Usuario encontrado:", user.user.tag);


                // Asignar el rol al usuario
                const roleId = "1206512326937939998"; // ID del rol que quieres asignar
                const role = guild.roles.cache.get(roleId);
                if (!role) {
                    console.log("No se encontró el rol");
                    return;
                }

                // Asignar el rol al usuario en el servidor de Discord
                user.roles.add(role)
                    .then(() => console.log(`Se ha añadido el rol ${role.name} al usuario ${user.user.tag} con éxito`))
                    .catch(error => console.error("Error al añadir el rol al usuario:", error));
            });
        });
    });
}
```

On Console returns:

C:\Users\Oscar\OneDrive\Escritorio\Proyectos\saladeros_roles>node xcadsjifjadsi.js

-> Conexión a la base de datos MySQL establecida
La columna 'users' está presente en la tabla 'roles'
Tabla roles creada o ya existente
ID de usuario obtenida: 1099807101603295303
No se encontró el servidor
La columna 'users' está presente en la tabla 'roles'
ID de usuario obtenida: 1099807101603295303
No se encontró el rol
La columna 'users' está presente en la tabla 'roles'
ID de usuario obtenida: 1099807101603295303
No se encontró el rol

I've tried to force the roles cache to be updated